# Azure restful webservice

Tags: c#, .net, azure

i'm trying to create a restful webservice and deploy it to Azure.

I can't figure out how this should be done. The MS documentation is huge and doesn't say much on how to achieve this.

I created a Cloud Service Azure Project and included a ASP.NET MVC4 WEB API WebRole and Visual Studio automatically created a website.

WebRole is the entry point for the service right? I don't see how the WebRole is connected with anything  in the project. I guess i'm totally missing some parts of this architecture.

Can you please tell me what's the best way to achieve this or point me to some helpful tutorials?

When should one choose to create a WCF Cloud Service?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Step-by-step instructions for creating a RESTful API in MVC in Windows Azure are [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/rest-service-using-web-api/). You should not be thinking about hosting a RESTful API in WCF - while possible there is a lot of unnecessary overhead.

If you are into Node.js, you might want to look at the new [Custom API](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/call-custom-api-dotnet/) feature in Windows Azure Mobile Services.